# Knockout.JS " Variable is not a function"

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript, visual-studio-code, durandal

I have a simple page with a filter button to select a list of users and another button to view a PDF with the list of users.

When I directly click View PDF the page loads correctly.
When I filter the page and then run the same View PDF button I'm left with "user.userID() is not a function"

In both cases I'm hitting the below code, Why do I get an error after filtering?

```
for user in viewModel.users()
   if user.isChecked()
       tempusers += user.userID() + ','
```

Comment: Is user.userID an observable? Based on the error message, I would guess it is not.

Comment: I have self.users = ko.observableArray([]), Do you have to declare all elements within the array in order to use them?

Comment: If you want them to be observables, you do need to declare them as such. Your code would probably work without `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout observables are functions, as such you need the parenthesis () in order to access the value. If you have your users set up as `self.users = ko.observableArray([])` then the collection of users (`self.users`) is observable and you will see changes and stuff when something happens to that object. The objects that are contained in the collection (and the properties of those objects) are not automatically observables, you would have to set it up that way when you add objects to it.

You should be able to access a 'user' object and it's properties without the parenthesis if it is not observable, like this:

```
for user in viewModel.users()
   if user.isChecked
      tempusers += user.userID + ','
```

If your 'user' was observable AND the properties of the 'user' were observable, then you might have to do something like this: `user().isChecked();`